# How to implement live stream with HLS using html and js

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, video-player, hls.js

**I am implementing Live streaming in my HTML video player but there is no live tag to show that streaming video is live or not?**

**I am using HLS.js for this.**

how can resolve this problem...?

```js
fluidPlayer(
        'hls-video',
        {
            layoutControls: {
                fillToContainer: false,
                autoPlay: true,
                title: 'My video title',
            }
        }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/3.0.0/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>
    <video id='hls-video' width="560" height="315" poster="">
        <source src="https://ottrbintl3.republicworld.com/httppush/ottrbintl_republic_hindi/chunklist_4.m3u8" type='application/x-mpegURL'/>
    </video>
```

Comment: _"but there is no live tag to show that streaming video is live or not?"_ Not clear. Can you get the video playing? If yes, what else is the problem? If you want some text or graphic saying "LIVE" then you must add it to the web page.

Comment: yes I get the video and it's playing but there is no indication text or graphic saying 'LIVE', how can i do that ?